# Why aren't Stack Exchange sites responsive to browser size?

Tags: support, design

I tend to browse websites with the browser taking up half the screen. This way, I can do multiple things at once, such as edit my code on the left half of the screen while researching documentation or tricks on the right (note: I usually do not have access to multiple monitors, as I use school computers most of the time). Unfortunately, of the many websites I visit for programming assistance, the Stack Exchange sites are one of the worst. Stack Exchange doesn't respond the the smaller browser size, making it hard to access the different features of the site. As an example, I took this screenshot visiting the site on my personal monitor, which has resolution 1920x1080 and is a rather large 24 inches:

[image]

Not too bad, but I cannot easily find the "Ask Question" button. Side-ways scrolling is such a dismal thing, but at least I can kind of see the HNQ list. This works okay with this monitor, but ideally the Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, Unanswered, and "Ask Question" buttons would be shifted further to the left to make them accessible on a smaller browser.

---

Things are about to get bad...

---

My laptop's monitor is a sad 1366x768 and 15.6 inches. This is what it looks like on my laptop. I know that my laptop's monitor is rather small compared to monitors out there, but I still expect to be able to use the site easily:

[image]

It's barely possible to navigate! Where is the "Questions" button? Only due to my repeated use of the site do I know that that tiny sliver of orange is how I can visit the question list. Let's try this out on the most popular [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/1896169) (rather, the top answer to it):

[image]

I can't even read the entire question. Sure, I could scroll to the right, but that is not something I ever remember how to do when navigating web pages.

Is there some reason why the Stack Exchange sites are not responsive to the browser size? Is the assumption just that the users of the site use big/multiple monitors (meaning targeting employees rather than random internet users)? Would the images and text just scale badly for some reason?

Comment: The layout of the SE engine is extremely complicated - when they expanded the sidebar just a little bit, there were *heaps* of problems created. Can you imagine how many problems there would be if they recreated the entire thing so that it is responsive? Coding a website as complicated as this so that it is responsive is extremely hard.

Comment: Answered by Shog [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179781/284336).