# Some chat room search bars are out of place when pages are around 1000 px wide

Tags: bug, chat, design

I view Stack Exchange in a browser window that is about 1000px wide. Because most of the site content is fixed to display with a page width of around 1000px, it all works.

Recently I've noticed that all is not well in chat when I do this, though. Many chat rooms including sites that don't have a layout (largely beta sites) and some designed sites, the "search" bar is misplaced:

[image: Screening room search bar misalignment]

Other sites, with smaller buttons, are fine:

[image: ELL chat room aligned properly.]

Both of these images are over 1100px wide, not even just 1000.

Yes, I can make my window slightly bigger to make the alignment fit but this hasn't always been an issue and not all users can make their pages wider. Heck, some users [complain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276820/why-arent-stack-exchange-sites-responsive-to-browser-size) that the site is too wide with a fixed width of 1000 px.

Please make it so that the chat pages render properly when the window is only 1000 px across.

---

#### NOTE! - Not asking to remove the fluid layout from chat. It should definitely expand when your window is wider. Just asking that it work properly at the width of the site's own default layout width.